# How can I change the style of last element in a list?

Tags: javascript, list, function, dom, addeventlistener

i have a function and event listener and inside them there are other functions and event listeners and so on.
it works fine but for example if i want to change only the last element the code doesn't work (it doesn't throw any error or anything just straight up does nothing)

bear in mind that i want to get the last element of a `<ul>` that's being created in DOM by javascript

for example

```
function fonter () {
    text.style.fontSize = "20px";
    text.style.fontFamily="cursive";
}
font.addEventListener("click" , fonter);
```

this works perfectly fine but the problem is it changes the font of every element
but for example if i change it to

```
  text.lastChild.style.fontSize = "20px";
```

it does nothing. have it in mind that if i console log  `text.lastChild` it shows the last child.

so 2 questions here . why doesn't this work even thou when i console log it , it shows up , and 2nd what's the best way to change like style or innertext or ... of last child in DOM? thanks

thanks

Comment: Please provide some HTML so we can see the complete picture. Also, find your shift key and capitalize properly. Respect your readers.

Comment: Do you know the difference between [`lastChild`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Node/lastChild) and [`lastElementChild`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Element/lastElementChild)? What is `text`?